# React Router Infinite Loading Issue When Navigating to Edit Route. Card component is not getting displayed in my EditTodo page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm working on a React Todo app where I'm using React-Router to navigate between different routes. I've encountered an issue that I'm struggling to resolve.

**Problem:**
When I navigate to the edit route `"/todos/:id"`, the page loads infinitely and doesn't display the expected content. The initial data fetching seems to work fine, but the rendering of the `UpdateCard` component is causing the problem.

**Expected Behavior:**
Upon clicking the "Edit" button, I want to be taken to the edit route `"/todos/:id"` and see a card component similar to the `AddTodo` component. This card should allow me to update the title and description of the todo item. I have already implemented my backend which has the logic to delete, add, and update todo.

**Current Behavior:**
Instead of displaying the expected card component, the page is stuck in an infinite loading loop.

**Steps I've Taken:**

- I've confirmed that the initial data fetching using Axios works as
  expected.
- The `EditTodo` component uses the `useParams` hook to fetch the
  specific todo's data.
- I've checked the console for any error
  messages, but there are no errors displayed.

**Code:**
Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

App.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css'
import TodoList from "./TodoList";
import axios from "axios";
import AddTodo from "./AddTodo";
import EditTodo from "./EditTodo";
import 'tachyons';

// hook
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos", {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setTodos(data))

    setInterval(() => {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos", {
        method: "GET"
      })
        .then((response) => {
          response.json().then((data) => {
            setTodos(data);
          })
        });
    }, 10000)
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = async(todoId) => {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/todos/${todoId}`);
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/todos");
    const data = response.data;
    setTodos(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="tc">
        <h1>TodoRobots </h1>
      </div>

      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/todos"
          element={
            <>
              <div>
                <AddTodo />
              </div>
              <div>
                <TodoList todos={todos} onDelete={handleDelete} />
              </div>
            </>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/todos/:todosId"
          element={<EditTodo todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

EditTodo.jsx

```
import { Button, Card, CardActions, CircularProgress, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function EditTodo() {
  let {todosId} = useParams();
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
    
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/todos/${todosId}`, {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("Todo response:", res.data);
        setTodo(res.data.todo)
      })
  }, []);

  if (!todo) {
    return <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
      <CircularProgress />
    </div>
  }

  return <div className="tc">
    <UpdateCard todo={todo} todosId={todosId} />
  </div>
}

function UpdateCard({ todo, todosId }) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(todo.title);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(todo.description);

  return <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
    <div className='tc br3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5'>
      <Card style={{ width: 300,  minHeight: 200, padding: 8 , backgroundColor:"#9eebcf"}}>
        <div>
          <TextField
            onChange={(e) => {
              setTitle(e.target.value);
            }}
            label="Title"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            style={{ marginTop: 16 }}
          /> 

          <TextField
            onChange={(e) => {
              setDescription(e.target.value);
            }}
            label="Description"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            style={{ marginTop: 16 }}
          />
                
          <CardActions style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", marginTop: 20 }}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              size="large"
              onClick={async () => {
                await axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/todos/${todosId}`, {
                  title: title,
                  description: description
                });
                alert("Todo updated successfully");
              }}>
                Update Todo
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </div>     
        </Card>
      </div>
    </div>
}

export default EditTodo;
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue. Why is the page loading infinitely when I navigate to the edit route, and how can I fix it? Is there something I'm missing or any suggestions for debugging?

Comment: What I personally feel is somehow I am passing empty todo to UpdateCard?

Comment: I don't see any overt issues here. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the render looping issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly you are observing? Is the app stuck in a render loop, or are you really just seeing the `CircularProgress` being rendered and the `todo` state isn't updated to a truthy value? What is the result of `console.log("Todo response:", res.data);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Check response from server, it may not be in correct format. e.g res.data.todo may not have the todo key. That's causing the state to be null and you show loading component when it's null. Changing todo key using correct format should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this ajeet. Have updated this in my code but issue still remains the same. Here is the updated code : 
https://gist.github.com/Vishalkr17/a65f1a0f1cfa2be0b25eaf1968378a04

Comment: Post error, console logs of variable, network output. Difficult to debug looking at code.

Comment: There's no dependency here, so I don't believe the state update is causing any render looping. This isn't fundamentally different than the OP's code. IDK why/how, maybe somehow OP's problem was fixed, but I don't think this answer was it. If OP still has issue then I don't know why they accepted the answer.

Comment: @DrewReese you are right the problem was that the setState was not setting the state as response from server was not in correct format. I will edit my answer. I can't delete as it's already marked correct

Comment: Oh, are you saying you think the issue isn't an infinite render loop, but rather the OP's code never stops rendering the `CircularProgress` component because the local `todo` state never becomes truthy?

Comment: Exactly  @DrewReese . That is the actual issue

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using todoId, in the updateCard component without passing it into it.

```
function UpdateCard({todo}) {}
```

But you are using it inside the function.

```
function UpdateCard({todo}) {...
```

---

Can you check in the handleDelete function. You should better wrap it inside try-catch block and also, do try using timeout for the requests inside the code.

Comment: Yeah , I have added that. Thanks Prino . But still the main issue persists

Comment: Try adding a timeout Promise for the axios.delete request. And catch the error, if something is wrong there, you should be able to rectify it.